# Hide WordPress page title

Tags: wordpress

I've created a page and set it as my main index page for my blog. My problem is that it displays the title of the page. Is there any way to hide the title for that particular page? I know by editing the template file I can remove the page titles, but that would remove the title for every pages.

Thanks

Comment: Just create a custom template.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be using CSS, so you only need to add a rule to your stylesheet that hides the title on the home page.

Good themes add a lot of semantic CSS `class`es to the HTML markup. The [TwentyEleven](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyeleven) theme for example, will add the class `home` to the `<body>` tag of the home page.

This way you could hide the page title for the home page this way:

```
.home .entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

The details may vary depending on the theme you are using.

In general, this is a very powerful tool for adapting pages according to type or category. Just check out the classes that your theme adds to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use `conditional tags` like -

```
if( is_page() )
// Show this
else
// Show that
```

Check codex [Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for more options

Answer (score 0):

Just duplicate that page template file. Rename it to something that it's related to.

And at the top:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: New Name Page
*/
```

Where you see the above, make sure you change the name of the template to something unique.Also remove the title from your new page template file so it wont show for that specific template.

Now you can select the page template for your page(Where you dont want the title to show).

Just go to your page in the backend and you should see under the Page attributes:

[image]

Now you can select your page template for that page. You can also set that page as the home page by going to Settings - Reading.

You can read more about page templates here http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates